# Why assignment inside loop not influence the global value?

Tags: bash

I have next `data source` and `code`:

**data:**

```
1
2
3
```

**test.sh:**

```
s=0
cat data | while read oneline
do
    v=$(($oneline))
    s=$(($s+$v))
    echo $s
done
echo "Final: $s"
```

**Execution:**

```
$ ./test.sh
1
3
6
Final: 0
```

What I want to do is sum all values in the data file, you could see the `echo` inside loop successfully print the sum step by step, but outside the loop, we got `Final: 0`, it should be `Final: 6`. What mistake did I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes create subshells. The while read is running on a different shell than your script. The following will fix it

```
s=0
while read oneline
do
    v=$(($oneline))
    s=$(($s+$v))
    echo $s
done < data
echo "Final: $s"
```